# Maple not displaying graph

Tags: graph, maple

Maple is only producing a description of a graph, e.g.

C := `Graph 9: an undirected unweighted graph with 66 vertices and 219 edge(s)`,

rather than displaying the graph. Can anyone please help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the command **DrawGraph** in the **GraphTheory** package. So, if **GraphTheory** is already loaded (with **with(GraphTheory)**), then issue the command **DrawGraph(C)**. If it isn't loaded, then use **GraphTheory:-DrawGraph(C)**.

There are many options for different ways to draw the graph, which you can read about on the help page **?DrawGraph**.